# Blank Image When Using localStorage to Store & Retrieve a PNG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Trying to load & retrieve image to/from localstorage.  The content security is not a problem I guess.

Somewhere the code is breaking either the image not stored correctly in local storage or image not loaded correctly from local storage.

Below is the Code to check whether the image is available from localstorage.  If available from session get it from the localstorage.  Otherwise get it from the URL and show the image and also store in localstorage.

The below code will get execute at `pagebeforecreate`

```
    var dataImage = localStorage.getItem('ses_image');

    var img = $('<img crossorigin="anonymous" width="100%" height="100%" id="img_menu-item" style="height: 100%;width:100%">');
    jQuery('#pg_home_content').append(img);

    if(dataImage){
        bannerImg = document.getElementById('img_menu-item');
        bannerImg.src = dataImage;
        jQuery('#pg_home_content').append(bannerImg);
    }else{
        img.attr('src', 'http://example.com/myimage.png');
        bannerImage = document.getElementById('img_menu-item');
        bannerImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
        localStorage.setItem('ses_image', imgData);
    }
```

**getBase64Image**

```
function getBase64Image(img) {

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  return dataURL;
}
```

When I did `console.log(dataURL)` it generates the below output and I guess there is something wrong...

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

For the first time the image got loaded and from second time onward I am getting a blank image... Not sure what I am missing???

Comment: Are any errors logged at `console` ?

Comment: @guest271314 No, there are no errors at console.

Comment: Tried without including `"image/png"` at call to `.toDataURL()` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Tried now.. its the same result... Actually I am trying to load 2 images (in the question I asked for one).  I noticed that the output of `dataURL` is same for both the images.... Ideally it should not be the same right???

Comment: Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 http://plnkr.co/edit/t4zhDYWP7seFPopMtnUV When the page loaded for the first time the image is shown.  When the page got refreshed the image has not shown...

Comment: Does plnkr return expected results ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103394/discussion-between-malaiselvan-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has not fully loaded by the time you write it to local storage. A blank image gets stored in local storage instead - and retrieved on subsequent visits.

To make sure the image loads before you write it locally, create an `onload` event handler for the image.

In your code, change:

```
    img.attr('src', 'http://example.com/myimage.png');
    bannerImage = document.getElementById('img_menu-item');
    bannerImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
    localStorage.setItem('ses_image', imgData);
```

to:

```
    console.log('loaded from url');
    bannerImage = document.getElementById("img_menu-item");
    bannerImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    // set the source of the image, equivalent to img.attr('src',...), but
    // slightly more performant
    img[0].src = "http://demo.jeema.org/mob20/media/com_jeemasmsmobile/menuicons/book.png";
    // delay writing to localstorage, until the image loads completely:
    img[0].onload = function () {
        imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
        console.log('writing to local storage:\n' + imgData);
        localStorage.setItem('ses_image', imgData);
        console.log('image stored');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I believe instead of `img[0]` in my case it is `bannerImage`.  The image got loaded now, however I am getting a different problem (happy to raise a separate thread) Since I am calling this method inside a loop and onload is `async` the image always stored in the last variable in the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you explain the second problem you're having?

Comment: Raised an another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387534/calling-image-onload-inside-a-loop-with-global-variable

Comment: Glad you found a resolution!