# Calling image onload inside a loop with global variable

Tags: javascript, local-storage, onload

The variable `menuitems` is a key value pair.  The key contains the name and the value contains the Image url.  The idea is to store the below URL in the localstorage.

Local Storage variable is `key_icon` (key is the name of the image)

Below is the code.  Assume there are 4 keys as `account`, `sms`, `group` and `history`.

```
$.each(menuitems, function(key, value) {
    menu_icon_session_name = key+'_icon';
    var dataImage = localStorage.getItem(menu_icon_session_name);

    //The Div container to load the image
    div  = "<div class='ui-block-a'><div class='ui-bar' id='div_"+key+"' style='padding:5px'>" +
    "<img crossorigin='anonymous' width=150 height=150 id='btn_"+key+"' style='height: 100%; width:100%'>"
    "</div></div>";

    //Append the div container with empty image
    jQuery('#pg_home_content').append(div);

    //Based on the local storage load the image
    if(dataImage){
        console.log('loaded from session');
        bannerImg = document.getElementById('btn_'+key);
        bannerImg.src = dataImage;
        jQuery('#div_'+key).html(bannerImg);
    }else{
        console.log('loaded from url');
        bannerImage = document.getElementById('btn_'+key);
        bannerImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        bannerImage.src = value.menu_icon;
        bannerImage.onload = function () {
            imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
            localStorage.setItem(menu_icon_session_name, imgData);
            console.log('stored '+menu_icon_session_name);
        }
    }
});
```

Since the `onload` is `asynchronous` the variable `menu_icon_session_name` is overwritten and all images are stored on the last variable `history_icon`.

All I am trying to do is load all the 4 images to separate localstorage and use it later...

Comment: You are creating 4 global variables that do not need to be global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...stuff...

    bannerImage.src = value.menu_icon;
    bannerImage.attr('data-my-session-name', menu_icon_session_name);
    bannerImage.onload = function () {
        imgData = getBase64Image(this);
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('data-my-session-name'), imgData);            

...stuff...
```

Comment: be careful not to use `getBase64Image(bannerImage)` but `getBase64Image(this)` instead, as `bannerImage` will always be only the latest image

Comment: I never thought of this... Works great... Thanks